# Sed removing last 4 characters in a file text inside a folder

Tags: linux

This is a linux problem
So I need to make a folder called "Notes", and inside that folder I need to make 6 files. The files are named with ID number, as follows:

- a00144998.txt
- a00154667.txt
- a00130933.txt
- a00143561.txt
- a00157888.txt

The first 3 letter are always "a00", and the 4th & 5th letter are the year. So I now need to copy the ID number/title of file without the '.txt' extension, and paste it on a new file outside the folder "Notes"
Example file a00144998, it shows year 14(from the 4th & 5th letter), so I will copy a00144998 to a new file named "year14.txt" and sort it. Same as a00154667, it shows year 15, so I will copy a00154667 to a new file named "year15.txt". So at the end, file "year14.txt" will have :

```
a00143561
a00144998
```

I have found the code, and it works if the files are not in the folder. But once I create files inside folder, this code doesn't work, it keeps copying the txt extension. Any idea? Thanks!

```
ls ~/Notes/???14????.txt|sed 's/.\[4\]$//'|sort>year14.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for `sed`, you can do it all in a bash oneliner:

```sh
for f in a0014*.txt; do echo ${f:5:4}; done | sort > year14.txt
```

This will loop over every file matching [the glob](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/pattern-matching-bash) `a0014*.txt` and put each string in an `f` variable, echo out `4` characters starting after the `5`th character.

TLDP has a great guide on [string manipulation in bash](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html).

You should also [avoid parsing `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). It's meant to be human and not machine readable.